# How to use a control character in a redis-cli argument?

Tags: bash, redis, control-characters

What I am trying to execute from my bash script:

```
redis-cli srem myset "abc\x06def"
```

`\x06` part seems to be ignored.

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, if these have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash I suggest:

```
redis-cli srem myset "abc"$'\x06'"def"
```

---

For checking the existence:

```
echo "abc"$'\x06'"def" | hexdump -C
```

Output:

```
00000000  61 62 63 06 64 65 66 0a                           |abc.def.|
00000008
```